# Configuring Kubernetes CronJob dependency

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to have a Job dependency in CronJob? I want JobB to be triggered after the JobA completes. 
  Or, Job C to be triggered after the JobA & JobB completes.

Answer (score 3):

This is not offered by kubernetes itself, but you can write your own kubernetes operator to implement that scenario.

There are API bindings for several programming languages and this task should be quite easy. You might want to investigate custom resource definitions as well to provide an API for dependent jobs to your end users (that is then implemented by your operator).